# Locate the coordinate based on change in pixel color

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, colors, pixel

I am trying to locate specific coordinates in an image. I have an image that contains only 2 colours, pink and black as shown in the image. If I know an (x,y) coordinate in the pink region (marked in yellow dot at the centre) how can I find the coordinates that are in the boundary of the pink region(as shown in yellow dots at the boundary).

[image]

NB: The yellow dots are not part of the image and I'm using this just to represent the region of interest.

I just want to know whether there is any fast and better approach for doing this other than nested for loops which may really slow down the process because I've to find the boundary coordinates in multiple regions of the image.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way using Python/OpenCV and Numpy.

- Read the input
- Convert to gray
- Otsu threshold
- Crop the row containing the center
- Get all the coordinates in the row that are white
- Print the first and last coordinate
- Draw line on input
- Save results

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image
img = cv2.imread("pink_blob.png")
hh, ww = img.shape[:2]

# convert to gray
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# center coords
center = (115,82)
cy = center[1]

# crop row at y center
row = thresh[cy:cy+1, 0:ww]

# get coordinates along row where it is white
# swap x and y between numpy and opencv coords
coords = np.argwhere(row==255)
num_coords = len(coords)
start = coords[0]
end = coords[num_coords-1]
start_pt = (start[1],cy)
end_pt = (end[1],cy)

print(start_pt)
print(end_pt)

# draw line from start to end coordinates on input
result = img.copy()
cv2.line(result, start_pt, end_pt, (255,255,255), 1)

# save result
cv2.imwrite('pink_blob_line.png', result)

# show result
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)

Start and End Coordinates:

(67, 82)
(160, 82)
```

Line on input image:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing, this was really helpful. The solution works perfect for this image, but is there anything that I can do to avoid the white lines going beyond the black region if there is another pink region along "cy". In that case its returning only the boundary of that pink region. I just wanted to stick to the pink region between the blacks

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Can you post a link to the questionable image?

Comment: Sure, Please see the image https://img.techpowerup.org/200721/testt.png I wanted to stick to the boundaries marked in green dots in the image

Comment: For that image, I would threshold. Then get contours and filter to keep only the largest contour. Then I would draw a white filled contour on a black background and then do the same as above.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, find contour of the pink region in the image. You can do this by first applying Otsu's thresholding on the image and then find contours using cv2.findContours().

Then in the contour boundary points, find the points having the same y-coordinate as that of the center pixel.

Among these points, point with the maximum x-coordinate will be the point on the right and point with minimum x-coordinate will be the point on the left.

Comment: Hi Rahul Kedia thaks for the reply. I have already done sematic segmentation in the input image as shown above. Do I really need to do Otsu's thresholding again?

Comment: If you have already done the segmentation, then I think you already have the contour. If yes, then there's no need for thresholding. It was only for finding contour.

Comment: The image shown here is the segmented image, I only have the roi  in pink and donno about the coordinates of the contour which we usually get from cv2.findContour

Comment: My approach is based on the contour data, thus to get it, you will have to do thresholding as findContours() function will take a binary image as input.